# PHP MessDetector Invalid Field Modifiers given

Tags: php, phpmd

I'm running this command:

```
sudo phpmd /repository/my/code/trunk/src/ text naming --reportfile code.staticanalysis
```

And getting this result:

```
Invalid field modifiers given, allowed modifiers are IS_PUBLIC, IS_PROTECTED, IS_PRIVATE and IS_STATIC.
```

This is a [fresh install](http://phpmd.org/download/index.html) of PHPMD, via pear. I have tried it with different and multiple rulesets (codesize, naming, unusedcode) for the same result. I had a suspicion the PDepend library might be bad, but reinstalling it didn't help. Any pointers?

Comment: make sure there is nothing in your source using the old style `var` property declarations. That might be throwing it for a loop

Comment: @Orangepill Can you be more specific what form the old style var declarations are? I'm not familiar and since this is legacy code there is a very good chance this is the problem!

Comment: example is `class A { var $property = "value"; }` instead of `class A { public $property = "value"; }` PHP 4 didn't support the visibility designation.

Comment: I did an extensive refactoring and search for issues related to `var` and replaced them with `public` or appropriate, and it's still dying. Does anyone know how I can get a stack trace to find the offending functions?

Comment: You may be able to get away with running your code through the command line `php -l` with `E_STRICT | E_ALL` set as the error reporting level.

Comment: `php.ini` is set with that already; it appears phpmd may be suppressing the additional information? This could be a limitation of that program.

Comment: is the code.staticanalysis file being created?

Comment: Yes, but it is empty.

Comment: What version of PDepnd are you using.... and try limiting the scope of the test to just include smaller code branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as I may I was unable to reproduce the issue that you where experiencing but  I did a little digging and this is what I found, hopefully it will lead to some sort of resolution:

The error you are describing is emitted as an exception of the `PHP_Depend_Code_ASTFieldDeclaration:::setModifiers` method call, it is thrown as a result of not having any modifiers for the method/class/property in question.

If I had to take a guess on what your issue was then I would say I might be because a version mismatch between PDepend and PHPMD. I would try uninstalling and reinstalling (I sourced mine from the pear repo if that makes any difference).

Good Luck.

Comment: So, after doing the above I spent a night exhaustively breaking down the codebase until I found the chunks that were failing. There were a couple of legacy instances of `interface MyInterface {` containing `private $_someVar`. I'm not sure if this ever worked in PHP but apparently it throws the somewhat misleading error message cited. Thanks for all your help @Orangepill !

Comment: Not a problem, glad you got it squashed... Thanks for turning me on to the tool.. it's pretty nifty.

Comment: I'll award the bounty as soon as I can... ~1 hr. Thanks again for your help!